# allow subdirectory index but no other pages in subdirectory

Tags: seo, robots.txt

In robots.txt...

I want to allow the index or homepage of the directory.

```
/landing/
```

I don't want to allow any other pages within the directory.

```
/landing/page  
/landing/anypage
```

How can this be done?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @RaymondChen, there are currently 979 other questions like this on Stack Overflow (2x as many as on Webmasters SE). If you really believe this question should be closed, you're gonna be a busy guy. More to the point, this is a programming question. This is what Stack Overflow is for.

Comment: How is this programming? It looks like web site configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
User-agent: *
Allow: /landing/$
Disallow: /landing/
```

According to Google Webmasters, you may only need the `Allow` directive:

[image]
<sub>*source: https://developers.google.com/webmasters/control-crawl-index/docs/robots_txt?hl=en#order-of-precedence-for-group-member-records*</sub>

Answer (score 0):

disallow: /landing/* should work.